# Good starting point for a workshop about web form UX?

Tags: forms, ux-field, workshop

I have to put in place a workshop dedicated to the UX of web forms and I need ideas/starting points because I have no previous experiences with workshops.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking. Are you asking how to start a workshop? Or what makes a workshop successful? I'm not even sure this is in the realm of this site

Comment: @Majo0od As dennislees figured out, it's more along the line of "How to make UX knowledge into a workshop?" ... but also "are there existing workshop templates for UX out there?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting point is determine and outline the structure of your content. This will likely be based on fundamental principles and best practices, and these can easily be researched.

To answer the obvious follow up question "How to make this into a workshop?" is too broad to answer here because there are too many unknowns, but in general, you should aim to:

- present a concept/topic (e.g form labels)
- discuss why certain approaches work/don't work
- offer opportunity to critique examples (either informally, via group discussion or formally in timed individual/paired/group sessions)
- repeat for major content areas and topics
- finish by providing participants with requirements for a form, and challenging them to apply their new knowledge to design a usable form

Comment: Well, that's the interactive part that I can't figure out. For example "offer opportunity to critique examples (either informally, via group discussion or formally in timed individual/paired/group sessions) " doesn't ring a bell ... would you have some practical example in mind? Do you know about tutorials/templates for workshops that can become truly interactive?

Comment: Never attended any workshop before :(

Comment: But surely you've been in a situation where you've been asked to talk about, think about, or work on something in pairs or small groups?  This is what's involved. It's hard to recommend this without sounding patronizing, but have you googled "how to run an interactive workshop"? The results for that search look interesting. If you genuinely have no idea what one looks like, the the best example I can think of (that I can find easily on Youtube) is this Design Thinking workshop. You can get a sense of the basic structure. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4gAugRGpeY